# Does God create fresh souls or are we a part of Gods soul?

Tags: nature-of-man, souls, immortality

With the premise that we have souls and the premise that the soul of God is eternal.

If God's soul is eternal, are the parts of that soul eternal too. If we are parts of that whole soul, then are we not eternal ourselves but occupy mortal bodies and simply pass on the eternal part of that whole soul?

Or does God create new fresh souls and we are not a part of God?

Comment: You appear to suggest that Deity has a 'soul'. And you appear to suggest that 'souls' can have 'parts'. This is metaphysical and philosophical, not Christian. I suggest it is off-topic on this site whose purpose is _comparative_ Christianity.

Comment: @NigelJ Yes, with respect, I asked the question in philosophy and got the same response as it was a theological Christian question.

Comment: I disagree with the 'premise' that Deity has a 'soul'. A soul is a created thing. Also your wording 'pass on the eternal part of that whole soul' is incomprehensible. No ; humans are not 'eternal' as we have a beginning. There is an element of truth in what you are attempting to convey, that 'in Him we live and move and have our being'. But your question cannot be answered without a comprehensive clarification, re-wording and re-defining of the question.

Comment: The OP would be better  if it referred to God's "spirit" rather than God's "soul."  But I rather like the idea of God growing as new souls are created!  Can an infinite God grow? Maybe God's concept of infinity is bigger than human limitations on infinity.

Comment: @NigelJ The human body is mortal and upon death returns to the earth whence it came. The soul once released from its mortal shell can either remain in the physical world or it can return to its spiritual beginnings. If it remains in the physical world either it can occupy a life form that does not have a soul or it can remain within the physical realm without a body. That soul if it returns to the spiritual realm can either be judged to oblivion or it can remain eternal as is its creator. If the soul remains in the physical realm then it is their eternally bodiless or not  Thinking logically

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8 None of the content of your comment is scriptural, which I suppose is the reason that you quoted none.

Comment: @NigelJ I'm a born Catholic but have never studied the bible I cannot quote scripture I have not read. However, that does not mean I do not have any faith. I posted the question as I have commented, because I don't think they liked it on philosophy SE. I just wanted to express my thoughts that's all I don't want to offend anyone if I have?

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8 I am certainly not offended myself. Personally, now in my seventies, I find that scripture itself is my education, my tutorage and is the only source I have ever found that gives genuine knowledge and real wisdom. I encourage you to read more of it. With kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Christian: The soul is part of the creature “human”. The premisse that God has a soul can not stand, so the answer to your question is that God creates new souls.

But there are many other religions with other ideas about God(s) and soul(s).

Comment: There is an alternative that a new soul is derived from its parents' souls and the concept of a first soul, which is in nature a temporal question.

Comment: there are lots of alternatives, but you only asked this question :)

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8 Human beings procreate and propagate _human nature_. Two humans contribute various characteristics to one progeny. But the unique person, soul and spirit, is a gift of the Creator himself : _each and every time_. 'In him we live and move an have being'.